# A conjectural inequality of the form $\int_a^b g(B'_1(t)) dt \le \int_a^b g(B'_2(t)) dt $ with convex increasing $g$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, calculus-of-variations, integral-inequality

Assume $ g:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty) $ be strictly convex and increasing monotonic function and $B_1:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty) $ be convex and increasing monotonic function and $B_2:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty) $ is increasing monotonic function and $B_1(t)>B_2(t)$ for every $ a<t<b $ and $B_1(t)=B_2(t)$ for  $t=a$ , $t=b$ then ***I guess that*** we can show $$\int_a^b g(B'_1(t)) dt \le \int_a^b g(B'_2(t)) dt $$

I have tried to use Jensen's inequality or other similar inequalities and also I have tried to use calculus of variation methods but I have not reached to any good place.

Can somebody give a counterexample or give hint to proof this even with some modification on hypothesizes

Comment: Integrate by parts.

Comment: @ec92 could you elaborate?

Comment: Or, even simpler, make the area over the top graph of stone, the area over the bottom one of paper, take scissors, and start cutting pieces off the area over the bottom graph carefully avoiding the stone. Translate what you see into induction/limits/whatever other math. dialect you like.

Comment: @fedja : thanks .I have reached this idea myself, but I didn't consider it as a  proof. I have guessed this inequality exactly in this way that you explained.

Comment: It is a finite process when $B_1$ is piecewise linear, so it is completely rigorous in that case. The general case follows by approximation as soon as you show that the piecewise linear functions inscribed into the graph of $B_1$ converge to $B_1$ in a strong enough sense to justify passing to the limit in the integral. In general, "a proof" is not as much a formal argument as a clear mental picture translated into a comprehensible language, and the ability to translate just comes with training and experience. :-)